# Maximum number of colors for embedding all colored perfect matchings in the complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory, extremal-graph-theory

For given $n>1$ I'm looking for the maximum number $k$ of colors such that there exists a $k$-coloring of the edges of the complete graph on $2n$ vertices with the property that a copy of every possible $k$-colored perfect matching is present in the colored complete graph.

For example, we know that there are $(n+1)$ 2-colored perfect matchings. On the other hand, we know that the complete graph can be decomposed into $(2n-1)$ perfect matchings (cf. Theorem 3.2 in 1-factorizations by Wallis). This gives $k>1$. On the other hand, for $(2n-1)$ colors we need to give each of the disjoint perfect matchings a dedicated color to accomodate the monochromatic perfect matchings. But then a perfect matching with $(n-1)$ edges of color $1$ and one edge of color $2$ cannot be present. So we have $k<2n-1$.

Can we improve upon these bounds?

**EDIT**: The problem seems to be harder than I thought, so I narrow it down.

Prove or disprove that $k=\omega(1)$.

Comment: From a quick computation, the number of distinct $k$-colored Perfect Matching is $\Theta(n^{k-1})$, while the number of perfect matching in $K_{2n}$ is $\sim\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^n < n^n$ (barring any mistake). Therefore if $k>n+1$, there is not enough PM in $K_{2n}$ to get all colored ones.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues: The number of distinct $k$-coloured perfect matchings is $\Theta(n^{k-1})$ only for constant $k$ independent of $n$. You can’t apply that with $k$ depending on $n$. For instance, the number of $(2n-1)$-coloured perfect matchings is $\binom{3n-3}n$, which only grows exponentially as $\left(\frac{27}4\right)^n$, so there are enough perfect matchings for large $n$. The only cases where this direct count improves the bound given in the question are $k\lt4$ for $n=3$ (as $20=\binom63\gt5!!=15$) and $k\lt6$ for $n=4$ (as $126=\binom94\gt7!!=105$).

Comment: @joriki, exact, my bad!